# Error when using fasttext in a Docker and setting only /tmp as writeable folder

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, fasttext

I am developing a metric in a docker with Python and I am using fasttext. I want to set all the folders as read-only, except for /tmp. The code works when I do not set it, but it crashes when I run the docker with this restriction. This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Instalar el compilador de C++ RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y python3 python3-pip RUN yum install -y unzip gcc gcc-c++ libsndfile sox 

# Update pip
# RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# RUN yum install -y python3-pip
# RUN pip install pybind11

COPY /cc.es.300.bin /tmp/cc.es.300.bin

# Copy and install requirements COPY /requirements.txt requirements.txt RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy python files COPY resource_managment.py ./ COPY app.py ./

CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

And the function that raise the error:

```
def load_fast_text_model():
"""
Loads a pre-trained FastText model from disk and sets it as the model to be used by the instance of the class.
    
Returns:
    The FastText model object that was loaded from disk.
"""
global fasttext_model
path_fast_text = "/tmp//cc.es.300.bin"
fasttext_model = fasttext.load_model(path_fast_text)
return fasttext_model
```

And this is the line that I use to run the Docker:

```
docker run --read-only --tmpfs /tmp --name image_metric -it -p 8080:8080 image_metric
```

I am missing something?